# Есть идея, нужны ваши советы

Tags: php, проектирование

Есть идея веб-приложения. Я знаю, какой функционал я хочу заложить, но я не представляю какой реализовать интерфейс для этого функционала, вообщем-то раньше у меня было что-то подобное но все валялось в виде отдельных php файлов и не представляло из себя цельного приложения, это было крайне неудобно, ведь здесь есть много сторон: юзабилити, возможные баги, интеграция и т.д. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста материал поизучать на тему проектирования интерфейса веб-приложения? Пока конкретная технология не интересует, планирую php + extjs, но по своим объемам проект требует внимательного проектирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую почитать книгу Стива Макконнела "Совершенный код". Думаю, там вы очень много для себя почерпнёте.

Comment: Удивительное совпадение, как раз читаю... Х)))
Но пока (мб пока) не нашел там ничего про проектирование интерфейса

Comment: А вы про какой интерфейс спрашиваете? Пользовательский (GUI), или про интерфейс программирования приложений (API)?